# A "standard" location for libpq headers on ubuntu?

Tags: c++, postgresql, ubuntu

I've installed libpq-dev on ubuntu with `apt-get install libpq-dev`. I see that its headers (e.g. libpq-fe.h) are in /usr/include/postgresql.

Now when I use gcc-4.8 to compile a program that says`"#include <libpq-fe.h>` (which is what the libpq doco recommends), it doesn't find the header.

Now I know I can solve this by (a) moving the headers to where the compiler expects them or (b) telling the compiler where to find them.  But what I'm writing is open-source software, and I want to minimize the burden on its users. I was hoping that if they installed libpq in a standard way, then the compiler would know how to find its headers. Or am I dreaming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are exactly two "proper" ways to find Pg headers:

- Using the `pg_config` binary to tell you where they are; or
- using `pkg_config`

The former is PostgreSQL-specific but portable. The latter requires `pkg_config` which is present mostly on Linux-like platforms, but is less Pg specific.